# Upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 - no change in desktop environment

Tags: unity, gnome, 18.04, launcher

I've upgraded using the software updater. The launcher still looks the same, the title bar is the same, the only change I see is in the look of the file manager. 
I am a noob at ubuntu. Is this normal? Should I manually install Gnome?

Comment: Lot of users have this issue. Installing Ubuntu 18.04 as a fresh is the quick solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was prompted during the installation to choose a display manager, I chose the default (LightDM) instead of GDM, so I didn't have the the option on the login screen to start Ubuntu or Ubuntu on Wayland.

After switching to GDM and booting the system, at the GDM login screen a cogwheel (⚙️) next to the sign in button can be found. Clicking on the cogwheel  should give an "Ubuntu" (and also an "Ubuntu on Wayland" option). This option logs into a default GNOME session instead of a Unity session.

Comment: Have you fixed  it by switching to GDM?

Comment: Yes, basically, and then I got the cog wheel on the login screen. I didn't have it before

Comment: Great! I have deleted my answer and added to yours to make it more complete.